# What constitutes of RValues?

Tags: c++, constants, lvalue, rvalue, temporary-objects

RValues are things which are not maniputable regions of memory, so literals like integers are considered RValues.

1. Do constants constitute RValues? `const int x = 0;` is maniputable at least one time.
2. Now, the temporary objects created by the compiler are also RValues even when they have maniputable memory regions. Why is that so?
   Because they cannot be modified by "users"? Is this the reason?

So, a memory region which is NOT maniputable by the "users" is called RValue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Do constants constitute RValues? const int x = 0; is maniputable at
>      least one time.

In your declaration, `x` is neither an rvalue or lvalue, it is called a *declarator-id*. (See grammar of 8/4 in C++03) When it is used in a (sub-)expression it is a non-modifiable lvalue which can be initialized to any *constant expression*.

> 2.Now, the temporary objects created by the compiler are also RValues even when they have maniputable memory regions. Why is that so? 
>   Because they cannot be modified by "users"? Is this the reason?

Rvalue of a class type can either be modifiable or non-modifiable but rvalues of built-in types are always cv-unqualified.

> § 3.10/9 Class rvalues can have cv-qualified types; non-class rvalues
>   always have cv-unqualified types.

Consider this example:

```
struct S {
     int x;
     void f(int s) { x = s; }
};

// ill-formed: Cannot assign to an rvalue of built-in type.
S().x = 42;

// Valid: A member function can be used to modify the referent of rvalue.
S().f(42);
```

The sub-expression `S()` creates an rvalue of class type whose lifetime is the end of ; *full-expression.*

Comment: What EXACTLY comprises of LValues?

Comment: "`S().x`" Hum... it isn't clear that this should really be rvalue: add an empty default ctor to `S`, then tell me what is the value of `S().x`?

Comment: @AnishaKaul "_What EXACTLY comprises of LValues?_" what the C++ standard says is a lvalue; for every C++ expression, look up the definition in the C++ standard to know if it is a lvalue.

Comment: @curiousguy: Nope, It won't make any difference because `S().x` is an rvalue expression which refers to a temporary object.

Comment: @curiousguy The standard doesn't say anything clearly on this, it says: `An lvalue (so called, historically, because lvalues could appear on the left-hand side of an assignment
expression) designates a function or an object. [ Example: If E is an expression of pointer type, then
*E is an lvalue expression referring to the object or function to which E points. As another example,
the result of calling a function whose return type is an lvalue reference is an lvalue. — end example ]
`

Comment: "_S().x is an rvalue expression which refers to a temporary object._" Yes, and this is impossible.

Comment: @AnishaKaul No, for every possible C++ expression, look up the definition of this sort of expression, there it says if it is a lvalue or a rvalue.

Answer (score 4):

Scalar rvalues are expressions that evaluate to scalar values like `42` or `i + k` (whereas scalar lvalues are expressions that evaluate to scalar objects like `i` or `*int_ptr` or `numbers[0]`).

rvalues of class type are expressions that evaluate to temporary objects. The most prominent example is the call of a function that returns a class object by value:

```
std::string foo()
{
    return "hello world";
}
```

Given the above function definition, the expression `foo()` is an rvalue. Note that I'm not talking about the *result* (which is a temporary object) but the *expression* `foo()` whose evaluation yields that result.

Comment: You should emphasize "values" and "objects" :-)

Answer (score 1):

An `lvalue` refers to a memory location and we can take the address of that memory location using the `&` operator. An `rvalue` is an expression which is not an `lvalue`.

`1. Do constants constitute RValues? const int x = 0; is maniputable at least one time.`

No, because you an do this - `const int *p = &x`

Comment: "_we can take the address of that memory location using the & operator_" Not always true.

Comment: @curiousguy: Can you give a counterexample?

Answer (score 1):

1. All variables, including nonmodifiable (const) variables, are lvalues. So x is an lvalue whereas 0 is an rvalue.
2. Temporary objects are made rvalues since they do not exist beyond that particular statement.

You can read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f90831hc.aspx)

Comment: Temporary objects sometimes persist for an entire block (or even until program termination).

Answer (score 1):

first of all - lval and rval are properties of expressions - an expression is either an rval or an lval.

To answer your other question, **temporaries** created by rvals can be modified by having a rval reference - this feature is added in c++11

This feature is very useful for 1) applying move semantics 2 ) perfect forwarding.

Read more about it at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/02/03/rvalue-references-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-2.aspx

Comment: "_And if you can get the address of the result of the expression with the '&' - then it means the expression is a lval. If not, then it's a rval._" this isn't true.

Comment: It's **often** true that `&lvalue` is valid and `&rvalue` is not, but not **always**. (If l/r-value were defined that simply...) The refutation is not new either: in C/C++, a struct member can be a bit-field `int i:2; // 2 bits value`; when named, this member really is a lvalue, but does not have an address, and it **not** an object.

Comment: "_rvals can be modified by having a rval reference_" First, **rvalues are expressions**. Expressions aren't modified, objects are. And rvalues of type `int` don't refer to objects. A rvalue **reference**, obviously, is a lvalue, as **names declared as references are always lvalues**. And this rvalue reference obviously does not refer to a rvalue, it refers to an object as all **references refer to objects**. So you are pretty much not modifying a rvalue here.

Comment: I only meant that the object created as a result of an rval expression can be modified through a rval reference, of course its not obvious in my post, I'll edit it

Comment: If you want a modifiable rvalue, here is one: `std::string() = "Hello, world";`

Comment: "_I only meant that the object created as a result of an rval expression_" But the expression `5` does _not_ create an object. Binding a reference to it does.

Comment: "_rvalues of type_" In my previous comment, I meant prvalue and glvalue. The new terminology, where "rvalue" is extended to almost-lvalue things, and lvalue is restricted so that not all references are lvalues, is too new and too confusing!

Comment: Is it that it does not create a temporary because its a built in data type? [ referring to "But the expression 5 does not create an object. " ]

Comment: Yes, a **prvalue** of a fundamental type does not refer to an object. (And here you see that it's important to use the new terms: glvalue, prvalue...)

Comment: Please see the edited post, is that better? My first SO post, and I've already learnt a lot!

Comment: @curiousguy: Only named rvalue references are lvalues. Unnamed rvalue references are xvalues.

Comment: @FredOverflow As I wrote: In my previous comment, I meant prvalue and glvalue.

Answer (score 1):

> RValues are things which are not maniputable regions of memory

**rvalues are expressions, not "things".**

rvalues *can* refer to objects ("maniputable regions of memory").

> so literals like integers are considered RValues.

Literals are rvalue (not "considered" rvalues) *because C++ is defined that way*.

> Do constants constitute RValues?

```
const int x = 0;
```

Actually, **`x` is a variable** of type `const int`.

Given the above definition of `x`, the expression `x` is a lvalue.

> Now, the temporary objects created by the compiler are also RValues

No, rvalues are expressions, **not objects**.

> even when they have maniputable memory regions. Why is that so?

It isn't so.

> Because they cannot be modified by "users"? Is this the reason?

rvalues are rvalues because the language is defined this way.

> So, a memory region which is NOT maniputable by the "users" is called RValue?

No, rvalue only designate expressions, not things that exist at runtime like memory.

A rvalue can sometimes refer to an object, which is a "memory region" that the user can manipulate.

> memory region which is NOT maniputable by the "users"

It isn't clear what you mean here; do you mean read-only memory, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

> RValues are things which are not maniputable regions of memory

Wrong. Rvalues absolutely are mutable. In C++03 doing this is a headache, but can be done legally- in C++11 it's extremely common.

Rvalues are expressions that yield things which are about to die. That's their defining property. Therefore, you can steal their resources without worrying about it, using C++11's rvalue references, or if you're desperate, "swaptimizing" in C++03. This makes them more correct in many situations, and much faster in *many, many* circumstances.