# How do temporary objects get created during Reference initialization?

Tags: c++, reference

How do temporary objects get created during reference initialization by the compiler, and what does that mean?

### EDIT

From the C++ standard:

> 12.2    Temporary objects                                                                [class.temporary]   Temporaries of class type are created in various
>   contexts: ***binding a reference to a prvalue*** (8.5.3), returning 1   a
>   prvalue (6.6.3), a conversion that creates a prvalue (4.1, 5.2.9,
>   5.2.11, 5.4), throwing an exception (15.1),   entering a handler (15.3), and in some initializations (8.5).

From this link: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr382.htm

> When a temporary object is created to initialize a reference variable,
>   the name of the temporary object has the same scope as that of the
>   reference variable.

Comment: Why do you think temporary objects are created during referennce initialization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your edit: 12.2 states that a temporary is created in the cases when you initialize a const reference where it refers to a prvalue. For example:

```
double d = 3.14;
const int &r = d;
```

the compiler transforms this code into something like this:

```
  int temp = d;         // creates a temporary int
  const int &r = temp;  // reference is bound to that temporary
```

The lifetime of temporary that is bound to a const reference is the lifetime of the reference. i.e. the temporary is destroyed when the reference goes out of the scope.

Comment: and the scope of the reference is limited to these `{}` braces?

Comment: Yes, the scope of const reference that is bound to a temporary is the scope in which a temporary is created, i.e. when you exit the scope the named const reference that is bound to a temporary is destroyed and destructor for the temporary object is called.

Comment: Thanks. :) Can you look in here too. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585924/what-constitutes-of-rvalues

Comment: Why did you say `const` reference? Isn't the same applicable for normal references?

Comment: No, because then it would depend on the lifetime an object. For example: A reference can be bound to an lvalue which may be a _static_ object whose lifetime is the end of program. When a non-const reference goes out of the scope it doesn't mean that object bound to that reference would get destroyed. On the other hand, you can only bind a const reference to an rvalue which refers to a temporary object. It gets destroyed as soon as the const reference goes out of the scope because it was supposed to extend the lifetime of a temporary object. I hope I understood your question.